# css hexagon; Chrome vs Firefox different size :before/after

Tags: css, html, fonts

I'm trying to make a hexagon, but for some reason it is different sizes in Chrome and Firefox.

Check out the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aa7o6m2L/

```
#packages .hexagon  {
  margin:-42px auto;
  width:65px;
  height:65px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.428;
}

#packages .hexagon:after  {
    font-family:arial;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -36px;
    left: -6px;
    content: "⬢";
    color: rgba(2, 135, 160, 1);
    font-size: 86px;
    line-height: 1.428;
}

#packages .hexagon:before  {
    font-family:arial;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -37px;
    left: -6px;
    content: "⬢";
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.09, 1.09);
    font-size: 86px;
    line-height: 1.428;
}

#packages .hexagon span  {
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 24px auto 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I've set font-family, font-size, line-height.

Any other ideas or suggestions would be great.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you seen this? http://csshexagon.com/

Comment: Im amazed there is a whole page dedicated to this...

Comment: yes and it makes an ugly hexagon:https://jsfiddle.net/aa7o6m2L/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the [unicode hexagon](http://graphemica.com/%E2%AC%A2) is rendering differently in Chrome & Firefox.

Google

[image: google]

Firefox

[image: firefox]

Why?  I don't know.